# How to store Remix Ethereum file?

Tags: solidity, remix, ico

I'm using remix ether to make a smart contract

However, I have no idea how to store information about contract.

If I turn off a computer or want to connect with other things, do i have to rewrite contract codes and deploy it?

There's other way how to save these things with .sol file with my computer?

As you know, If I deploy a contract there's menu on the right side at the conner. Here [image]

BUT NOW i missed everything with turn off the browser. please let me know to store it

Answer (score 1):

You can not save files in Remix, from what I know (they are saved in browser history, but when you clean it, you will lose it), so the simplest solution would be to copy the content of your file to the text file on your computer and save it. Then after you open browser again simply copy content of that file it to Remix. If you really don't want to lose that file just send it to your own email or smth, or store it on github.

Remix runs very fast so deploying it again to local network or JVM Enviroment is not an issue.

If you deploy your contracts to some public network (main, Kovan, Ropsten, Rinkeby) you need to save somewhere the address of that deployed contract so later you can provide that address in Remix to that field "Load contract from address" to interact with it again.

Answer (score 0):

As your code is still there (right?), use the address at which you deployed the contract in the field "load contract form address" and hit the button, all will appear again.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Download and restore backup in Remix]

After completing the code you can also download it as a Zip file and then use the restore backup button to restore the files.